# Help with baking

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, baking, uv-image-editor

[image]

How do I bake these "colours"?
When I follow a tutorial, the UV editor window where it shows what I bake ends up all black.

I want to export this so I can use in Spark AR because materials wont import so I heard I must Bake/unwrap the "colours". Blender noob .

Comment: *In short*: Add an image node and assign a new blank image to bake onto otherwise the bake button won't do anything.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.